# nth-child does not show as desired order

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to jquery. I am a bit confused here. There are only two buttons on the page. Why the two button elements are 2th, 3rd child, and "first-child" & "last-child" selector return nothing?

And I notice if I remove the the first p element, they would somehow work as desired.

---

[image]

Comment: Because they *are* the 2nd and 3rd children respectively?

Comment: [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) is what you are after, `nth-child` does not limit itself to the tag previously stated, in your case button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make it work ,like for nth-child(1) to get the 1st button in DOM
the you shoud use

```
$("button:nth-of-type(1)")
```

For more details [link](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .eq(x) to get a single child.

```
$("selector").eq(x) -> $("button").eq(0)
```

:nth-child() it's usually to CSS, but when u use jQuery u have functions that make that for u

edit:
[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`.

nth-child works as the child of the parent element and selects all elements in the order.

While nth-of-type will select only the similar sibling elements.